# How do I stop a PHP script running on the background

Tags: php, apache

I started this process (time.php)

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true); // run script in background
set_time_limit(0);       // run script forever 
$interval = 300;         // do every 1 minute...
do
{ 
    // add the script that has to be ran every 1 minute here
    // ...

    $to      = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Hello Richie";
    $header  = "From: me@xxxxxxxxx.org";
    $body    = "Hello Richard,\n\n"
             . "I was just testing this service\n\n "
             . "Thanks! ";

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

    sleep($interval); // wait 5 minutes

} while(true); 
?>
```

but I now want to stop it. It's sending hundreds of mail to my Gmail a/c. It's on a web server where I cant restart it to kill the process.

Is there a way to execute another file to kill the process, or how do I go about?

Comment: from the command line `kill <pid>`. And next time don't start what you don't know how to stop

Comment: Does your host give you access to the console (SSH)?

Comment: `ignore_user_abort(true);` + `while(true);` + `mail`  = `Very Bad`

Comment: This is the best question I've read all week! Add in the while loop the line `file_get_contents(time.php);` No seriously don't do that.

Comment: @Dagon somehow sounds like a high level wizard scolding a young apprentice practitioner.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't have shell access, then the only way is to ask the server administrater to kill the process.

That being said, there is an easy way to set up a script and enable it to be canceled from any other script on the same server, as follows:

```
<?php
// at start of script, create a cancelation file

file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir().'/myscriptcancelfile','run');

// inside the script loop, for each iteration, check the file

if ( file_get_contents(sys_get_temp_dir().'/myscriptcancelfile') != 'run' ) { 
    exit('Script was canceled') ; 
}

// optional cleanup/remove file after the completion of the loop

unlink(sys_get_temp_dir().'/myscriptcancelfile');

// To cancel/exit the loop from any other script on the same server

file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir().'/myscriptcancelfile','stop');

?>
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by cancellation file, I have a similar probem

Comment: file_put_contents() puts a file named "myscriptcancelfile" inside of PHP's /tmp folder, which is writable by the global PHP user on that server (could be any name specific to your script) with the contents of "run". During the looping iterations, file_get_contents() checks the contents. If the contents have been changed to anything other than "run" (say, by you to stop the script), the loop exits. For cleanup after the loop, you could do unlink('/tmp/myscriptcancelfile');

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you do not have shell access either. I suspect the easiest way is to contact the administrator and have them restart Apache. They don't want this running anymore than you do.

One alternative would to attempt to kill all the Apache processes using PHP. It will send a kill signal to all Apache processes, except the one it is running under. This might work if the Apache process running under a shared process without setuid(). Attempt at your own risk.

```
<?php
$cpid = posix_getpid();
exec("ps aux | grep -v grep | grep apache", $psOutput);
if (count($psOutput) > 0)
{
    foreach ($psOutput as $ps)
    {
        $ps = preg_split('/ +/', $ps);
        $pid = $ps[1];

        if($pid != $cpid)
        {
          $result = posix_kill($pid, 9); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, though it didn't tell which process to kill as my script was running with different id, I noted down different pids returned and they seemed to return some repeating ids, except few, so had to kill one of them.

Answer (score 5):

The following will stop the background process(PHP):

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

To start apache again:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

To simply re-start apache:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Answer (score 4):

If you started it in background use `ps aux | grep time.php` to get PID. Then just `kill PID`. If process started in foreground, use  to interrupt it.

If process started within Apache, restart Apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart for Debian). If process started with CGI-like server, restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

To stop your php scripts running you can simply enter the following command in your terminal. This will restart the Apache service. (ultimate restarting your php service).

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You may wish to include timeout's within your scripts in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the apache process running. Try running something like `apachectl stop` and then `apachectl start` to start it back up. This will kill your server for a period of time but it will also make sure that any processes stuck on that script will go away.