# PHP abort script after next request

Tags: php, centos

Let's say I have a php script called index.php. This script is running forever with set_time_limit(0) and running in background with & in centos VPS. Now when I request this script again, the previous script should stop and this script should start from scratch. The current problem is whenever I try to run this second time, the first script also running. I want to kill first one and start second one.

Comment: neverminding for whatever reason you would want to do such a thing, but i'd suggest using a file/database-field/whatever to write the current time when your script starts. this time is also put in a variable - after that, you just have to regularly read the file anew and compare the timestamp - if it differs, a newer instance has started and the current instance can abort.

Comment: Just gonna drop this here, don't know if it is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847462/how-do-i-stop-a-php-script-running-on-the-background

Comment: This sounds like a very odd approach to solve a task that has can be handled in a much more elegant and robust way. If you are interested in that then you should explain what task you are actually trying to solve and how you can do that instead of posting how you are _trying_ to solve it.